# Buggy expression with pre-increment operator from order of evaluation or temporary object?

Tags: c++

I use iterators to create substrings.  I tried using the pre-increment operator in an expression, but I get unexpected results.  I believe the snippet worked in part of my code, but when I cut/paste it into another function it behaved differently.  Compiler was MSVC 2019.

I now believe I have an [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) problem.  ***However, do I also have any kind of problem from a temporary object?***

What's the best practice for using increment operators in expressions?

```
using namespace std;
string str{ "The quick brown fox" };
cout << str << endl;

auto it{ begin(str) };
string str2(++it, it + 7); // Temporary object problem here?
cout << str2 << endl; // Observed "he qui". Expected "he quic".
```

Comment: What's wrong with `string str2(it+1, it + 8);` or `auto it{ begin(str) + 1 }; string str2(it, it + 7);` ?

Comment: The rules on how these kind of expressions are interpreted have changed significantly over the history of C++. No doubt someone could tell the full story but from a practical point of view the best advice is simply to avoid expressions where you increment a variable and also use its value elsewhere.

Comment: Your code has undefined behavior, roughly because the evaluations of the two constructor arguments are not ordered with respect to each other, and the order matters.

Comment: best pratice is to write readable code. If you have problems to understand, chances are high that the next one reading the code will have the same problems

Comment: "*However, do I also have any kind of problem from a temporary object?*" -- your program exercises undefined behavior.  That makes its whole execution undefined, mooting any question about what the Standard might specify if its behavior were defined.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Nothing wrong with your suggestions. I merely wanted to understand my bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MSVC2019 is a C++17 compiler.

And there is no issue with a "temporary object" here.

The order of evaluation of function arguments is unspecified. It's **not** *implementation-defined*. This means that you can't guarantee that you can elucidate the behaviour from the compiler documentation.

So you don't know if `it + 7` uses the original or incremented value for `it`.

Since you should try to avoid code that uses behaviour that's not specified by the standard in the interests of portability, the best practice is to avoid it.